# Constant area of triangle from tangent line and axes

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, area, tangent-line

> Let $f:(0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\not=0$ with the following property: the area of the triangle formed by the tangent line of $C_f$ at a point $M(x_0,f(x_0))$, $x'x$ and $y'y$ is constant and independent of $x_0\in (0,+\infty)$. Find all functions $f$ with the above properties.

I know that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}, x>0$ satisfies the above conditions.

**Attempt**

Let $\varepsilon_{x_0}:\ y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ be the equation of a tangent line of $C_f$ at a point $M(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $A\bigg(\frac{x_0f'(x_0)-f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)},0\bigg)$, $B(0,-x_0f'(x_0)+f(x_0))$
the intersection points of $\varepsilon_{x_0}$ with the axes. Then $(OAB)=c=\text{constant}\Leftrightarrow  (x_0f'(x_0)-f(x_0))^2=-2cf'(x_0)$.

**Questions**

1. Is there any reference of the above problem in the literature?
2. Is there an easy way to solve the differential equation $(xf'(x)-f(x))^2=-2cf'(x)$?

Comment: I think the differential equation should read
$$(xf′(x)−f(x))^2=−2cf′(x),$$
where $c$ is the constant triangle area. Also note that there are some solutions to the differential equation that do not satisfy the requirement on the image of $f$. E.g., for $c=4$ you also get the solution $f(x)=2−x$.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem means about "$x'x$ and $y'y$".

Comment: I also noted that differentiating the original equation you get $$f''(x)(x^2f'(x)-xf(x)+c) = 0,$$ which, according to WolframAlpha, has solutions with non null second derivative given by $$f(x) = kx+\frac{c}{2x}.$$ However, only $k=0$ guarantees that the original first order equation is satisfied!

Comment: @aschepler x-axes and y-axes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to connect and expand a little bit my comments.

Differentiating the equation
$$\left[xf'(x) - f(x)\right]^2=-2cf'(x)\tag{1}\label{1}$$
you get
$$f''(x)\left[x^2f'(x)-xf(x)+c\right]=0.$$
So **either**
$$f''(x) = 0,$$
yielding
$$f(x) = k_1 x + k_2,$$
which however does not satisfy the requirement $ f: \ (0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$, **or**
$$f'(x) = \frac1{x} f(x) -\frac{c}{x^2},$$
a linear ODE whose solutions are
$$f(x) = kx + \frac{c}{2x}.$$
Plugging in these solutions into \eqref{1} we get $k=0$. So **the only twice differentiable functions** that satisfy the hypotheses are of the form
$$\boxed{f(x) = \frac{c}{2x}},\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $c>0$ is the triangle constant area. I wonder what happens if you remove the requirement on twice-differentiability.

---

**EDIT**

Following the comment by [Alex Ravsky](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71850/alex-ravsky) one can note that equation \eqref{1} can be written in the form
$$x^2[f'(x)]^2-2(xf(x)-c)f'(x)+f^2(x) = 0,$$
which implies that at point $x>0$ the derivative can be computed as
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{c}{x^2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{c[c-2xf(x)]}}{x^2}.$$
Observe that this forces the condition $f(x)\leq \frac{c}{2x}$, for all $x>0$. Using now the derivative of composite (differentiable) functions we can determine that the second derivative of $f(x)$ does exist and is equal to
$$f''(x) = \frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}+\frac{3c}{x^3}\pm\frac{-x\ \boxed{\frac{\left\{c[c-2xf(x)]\right\}'}{\sqrt{c[c-2xf(x)]}}}-2\sqrt{c[c-2xf(x)]}}{x^3},\tag{3}\label{3}$$
valid for all points $x$ such that $f(x)<\frac{c}{2x}$, *unless $xf(x)$ is constant (in which case the third summand in \eqref{3} is just $\pm k/x^3$, for some constant $k$)*. The latter case confirms the solution \eqref{2}. The former does not apply, since we already know that the only function satisfying the original requirement and that has second derivative is $f(x) = \frac{c}{2x}$.

In conclusion, no other function $(0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$, aside from \eqref{2}, guarantees that the tangent at any point forms with the axes a triangle with constant area.

Comment: The differential equation provides the quadratic equation $x^2f'(x)^2+(2c-f(x))f'(x)+f(x)^2$ for $f'(x)$, whose roots are $\frac 1{2x^2}\left(f(x)-2c\pm \sqrt{(f(x)-2c)^2-4x^2f(x)^2}\right)$. I expect that this can be helpful to show that $f'(x)$ is differentiable at all but finitely many points $x>0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky It's actually $x^2[f'(x)]^2 -2(xf(x)-c) f'(x) + f^2(x)$, correct?